# How do you recover a hard-bricked Nexus 7 2012?

Tags: nexus-7, unbricking

I had a lollipop rom Nexus 7(2012), and I wanted to change it to Android Kitkat, as a personal like for it. I did as told in Google Developers page for Android Firmware for Nexus devices. When the process was halfway through, suddenly my computer shut down due to power failure(UPS Problem). And I cannot get it to go into fastboot, bootloader, recovery, download mode or whatever mode it is. Even charging symbol does not appear when I plug it in.

But it gets detected by the PC when I connect it. See the below picture:
[image: Nexus 7 2012 appearing as Unknown Device]

Does this have any way to un-brick it? If not by software, should we change the hardware like motherboard so that it could be fixed?

Comment: Does it turn on at all?  If not it sounds like the main board might be fried which is pointless to swap, you'd be better off with a new one.

Comment: It does not turn on. It does not even show a sign of its life

Comment: Yeah, you wont be getting that back to life soon. Better start shopping, you just killed the supposedly unkillable

Comment: If it is unkillable why isn't mine working... PS: But it is getting detected on my computer when I connect my usb to the computer!

Comment: Try if adb is working. Only then there may be a hope.